# How can I create a Nullable Optional Numeric (integer/double) parameter in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, nullable, numeric, optional-parameters

How can I create a nullable numeric optional parameter in [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

EDIT: this should be possible in VB.NET 10 according to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/wriju/archive/2009/11/08/vb-net-10-optional-nullable-parameter.aspx). If you're using it then you could have:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(Optional ByVal someInteger As Integer? = Nothing)
    Console.WriteLine("Result: {0} - {1}", someInteger.HasValue, someInteger)
End Sub

' use it
DoSomething(Nothing)
DoSomething(20)
```

---

For versions other than VB.NET 10:

Your request is not possible. You should either use an optional parameter, or a nullable. This signature is invalid:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(Optional ByVal someInteger As Nullable(Of Integer) _
                        = Nothing)
```

You would get this compile error: "Optional parameters cannot have structure types."

If you're using a nullable then set it to Nothing if you don't want to pass it a value. Choose between these options:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(ByVal someInteger As Nullable(Of Integer))
    Console.WriteLine("Result: {0} - {1}", someInteger.HasValue, someInteger)
End Sub
```

or

```
Public Sub DoSomething(Optional ByVal someInteger As Integer = 42)
    Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", someInteger)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't, so you'll have to make do with an overload instead:

```
Public Sub Method()
  Method(Nothing) ' or Method(45), depending on what you wanted default to be
End Sub

Public Sub Method(value as Nullable(Of Integer))
  ' Do stuff...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use an object:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(Optional ByVal someInteger As Object = Nothing)
If someInteger IsNot Nothing Then
  ... Convert.ToInt32(someInteger)
End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out in VS2012 version like

```
Private _LodgingItemId As Integer?

Public Property LodgingItemId() As Integer?
        Get
            Return _LodgingItemId
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Integer?)
            _LodgingItemId = Value
        End Set
    End Property

Public Sub New(ByVal lodgingItem As LodgingItem, user As String)
        Me._LodgingItem = lodgingItem
        If (lodgingItem.LodgingItemId.HasValue) Then
            LoadLodgingItemStatus(lodgingItem.LodgingItemId)
        Else
            LoadLodgingItemStatus()
        End If
        Me._UpdatedBy = user
    End Sub

Private Sub LoadLodgingItemStatus(Optional ByVal lodgingItemId As Integer? = Nothing)
    ''''statement 
End Sub
```